# Line by line analysis and plotting on multiple monitors during presentation

Tags: r, plot, rstudio, presentation, multiple-monitors

I am preparing a presentation on data analysis and I am provided with a 2-3 monitor and projector head-up. I would like to use one monitor(+projector) for code, one monitor(+projector) for console display and one monitor(+projector) for plots. Monitors are for me, projectors for the audience.

I would also like to run the code line-by-line (similar to the `Ctr-Enter` feature of RStudio); copy pasting code won't work. I want to use interactive graphics, analysis and plotting *on-the-fly* so any pre-done analysis won't work.

Is there any way to achieve this? Although Rstudio is a fantastic tool, a rather basic (and one might say easy) feature like panel detachment is not being developed although frequently requested. This would be  probably the best solution to what I want.

**UPDATE**: Any OS (Win, Mac, Linux) will do.

Comment: and your operating system is.... (also, heck of a setup with 3 monitors and projectors... I'd just want to play Flight Simulator on it all day...)

Comment: I'm flexible. Win, Mac, Linux, whatever will do the job. +1 for Flight Simulator

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the vanilla R GUI. Within that you have separate panels/windows for code, console, and plots (with as many plot windows as you want by calling a new device like `quartz()`). You can evaluate a line of code from the script using `Cmd-Enter`(mac) and `Cntr-Enter` (pc) plus the default settings highlight the line of interest. You could also use emacs in the same way, which I find much more powerful and fun.